# How to pass runtime parameters file for testers to run integration test from azure pipelines,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, integration-testing, azure-pipelines

We are actually working on azure pipelines where we want to pass the required parameters for integration test to run by the testers and see the output if the integration test is passed or not.I know we can use runsettings to pass the data - it is good for few variables, but we have lots of data to pass to semi automated integration test. Is there a way where can put all the test data in xml file or in some other fileformat which is required for the test to run and pass the file at runtime by triggering azure pipeline when testers run integration test.
one more options is where can use the parameters in template in pipeline, can i use this approach if so how do i get those values into Visual Studio when i run the integration tests..

Comment: Where do you run the integration tests, test plans in azure devops, azure pipelines or visual studio? Can you share the detailed steps of what you want to achieve(with screenshot would be the best)? Can you commit the test parameter file into your code repo and let your test code get the parameters from this parameter file. so that the testers can get the file along with the source code. Is [this blog](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-nunit-test-parameters-from-file.html) helpful to you?

Comment: We are running the integration test as part of the azure pipeline, and our plan is to make the testers run the integration tests by passing some parameters as we have lot of parameters to pass to integration test best idea would be to place all the parameters into file and pass that file in the pipeline and run the test targeting different environments like Dev, test. ex like passing the url, user name and password from runsettings file and testers can run the test plan run the tests.would like to know if there is any possibility of passing a file in the pipeline and integration tests.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1,You can check out [variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse), if your azure pipeline is in YAML file.

First define a template yaml file(eg. vars.yaml)

```
# File: vars.yml
variables:
  url: 'http://url'
  userName: "username"
```

Then in file azure-pipelines.yml, refer to template vars.yml in the **Variables** section

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
- template: vars.yml  # Template reference

steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    runSettingsFile: '**/*.runsettings'
    overrideTestrunParameters: '-url $(url) -userName $(userName)'
```

Note: variable template file has to be committed to your code repo too. It is only available in **Yaml pipeline**.

2, You can also try uploading the test parameter file as [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) in azure pipeline.

Then you can add [Download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) in your azure pipeline to download the parameter file at runtime. After it is downloaded by download secure file task, its path can be referenced in the pipeline as `$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)`. Alternatively, downloaded secure files can be found in the directory given by `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`.

You can then use [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to move around the parameter file in then build agent.

Note: using secure file makes it inconvenient to update the test parameters, you have to upload the test parameters file to azure devops each time you need update a test parameter. And it would be a problem to retrieve the test paramaters defined in the parameter file in the runtime of your pipeline.

3, You can also have a try using [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group). You can then store all the test parameters in the variable group. You can [Link the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group) to your pipeline. Then the test parameters stored in the variable group will be available in your pipeline.

In Visual Studio test Task you can easily Override test run parameters with the parameters defined in variable group. See below:

[image]

I would recommend using **variable group** in your pipeline. It is easy to maintain your test parameters in variable group, And it is reusable across multiple pipelines.

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question .. I will give it a try tomorrow.. Thanks once again 

Comment: I'm trying first option as our pipelines are in yaml. Cannot override as it erroring with 'Override test run parameters is not a expected property'. Will that be a part of arguments?? Could you please let me know where exactly I need to override the parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I may not be descriptive - what I meant is using first option   
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
  overrideTestrunParameters: '-url $(url) cannot do this as override Test run parameters is not valid in yaml pipeline.

Comment: As of now, I have a runsetings file which is having list of values which needs to be passed for test to run and in pipeline I'm overriding the value from Variables(which is available just next to run button in pipelines) using powershell.

Comment: I found there was an indentation mistake for `overrideTestrunParameters` in above yaml example. Sorry for this. I updated above yaml example. Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) for more information about vstest task.